# Unity система координат

Tags: unity3d

Почему 2 объекта, находящихся в точке (0, 0, 0) могут находится в разных точках? Оба находятся на самом верхнем уровне в иерархии. Пайвоты у них совпадают. Как такое может быть? Это из-за пайвотов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.․․2 объекта, находящихся в точке (0, 0, 0) могут находится в разных точках․․․`․   Простите, что?

Comment: @Арман transform position показывает, что оба находятся в (0, 0, 0), но если посмотреть на них то в разных, причем заметно это довольно четко

Comment: Можете хотя-бы показать скриншот, где это "довольно чётко видно"?

Comment: попробуйте `gameObject.transform.localPosition` вместо `gameObject.transform.position`

Comment: @МаксимБончев добавил

Comment: может один дочерний и у него (0, 0, 0) установлены по родителю?

Comment: @Methorn оба на самом верхе

Comment: Неправильный экспорт объектов.

Comment: При экспорте объекта он был смещен уже

Comment: @Methorn в префабе координаты 0 0 0

Comment: @abdelich А что именно не так? Или как правильно экспортировать?

Comment: не в префабе, а когда модельку создавали, что-то по типу вы расставили все детали по местам, начали экспортировать, а место относительно начала смещено

Comment: Либо если все правильно экспортировали посмотрите в самом префабе, заглянув в него. Может там смещено.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть центр модели смещён. Попробуйте сделать то же самое со стандартными кубами размером 1 юнит, они должны совпасть